# Using ModelState.AddModelError causing multi-threads and duplicate records insert

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net core code, I use the ModelState.AddModelError() in validation and it causes multi-threads and the code insert duplicate records into the table. Is there a way to prevent the issue? Thanks.

The Controller:

```
public IActionResult BudgetAdd(BudgetDocumentAddViewModel model)
{
    if ((model.ACCT.Length < 6) || (((model.FUND == "508") || (model.FUND == "760") || (model.FUND == "761")) && (model.ACCT.Substring(0, 2) != "50")))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ACCT", "Error: Incorrect Account (ACCT) Number!!!");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var document = new tDocument();
        document.FY = model.FY;
        document.FUND = model.FUND;
        document.AUTH = model.AUTH;
        document.DEPT = model.DEPT;
        document.DOCU_TYPE = model.DOCU_TYPE;
        //Need to get the largest DOCU_ID. Cannot rely on the DOCU_ID from the form.
        //document.DOCU_ID = model.DOCU_ID;
        document.DOCU_ID = _docManager.GetDocuID(model.FY, model.FUND, model.AUTH, model.DEPT, model.DOCU_TYPE);
        document.ENT_DT = model.ENT_DT;
        document.BUD_YR = model.BUD_YR;
        document.ORG = model.ORG;
        document.ACCT = model.ACCT;
        document.DOCU_DT = model.DOCU_DT;

        if (model.DEPT_OBJ.Length >= 3)
        {
            document.OBJ = (model.DEPT_OBJ).Substring(0, 3);
            if (model.DEPT_OBJ.Length == 5)
            {
                document.SUB_OBJ = (model.DEPT_OBJ).Substring(3, 2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.OBJ = "";
            document.SUB_OBJ = "";
        }
        document.DESP = model.DESP;
        //document.AMOUNT = model.AMOUNT.ToString().Replace(",", string.Empty);               
        var sAmount = model.AMOUNT.ToString();
        sAmount = sAmount.Replace(",", string.Empty);
        document.AMOUNT = Decimal.Parse(sAmount);
        document.RECV_DT = model.RECV_DT;
        document.OUT_DT = model.OUT_DT;

        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "002120")
        {
            document.OBJ = "212";
        }
        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "002130")
        {
            document.OBJ = "213";
        }
        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "003030")
        {
            document.OBJ = "605";
        }
        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "003040")
        {
            document.OBJ = "304";
        }
        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "003090")
        {
            document.OBJ = "609";
        }
        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "004430")
        {
            document.OBJ = "607";
        }
        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "006010")
        {
            document.OBJ = "601";
        }
        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "006020")
        {
            document.OBJ = "602";
        }
        if (model.FUND == "100" && model.ACCT == "007300")
        {
            document.OBJ = "730";
        }
        //To get the username from the AspNetUsers table and assign it to the User_ID field in the tDocuments table.
        document.USER_ID = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        _docManager.AddDocument(document);

        return RedirectToAction("BudgetSearch", "Document", new { FY = document.FY, FUND = document.FUND, DEPT = document.DEPT, AUTH = document.AUTH });
    }

    model.Divisions = _docManager.GetOrganizations();
    return View(model);
}
```

The View:

```
@model test.ViewModels.BudgetDocumentAddViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Budget Add Document";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("BudgetAdd", "Document", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1 class="panel-title">Add Document</h1>
        </div>        
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOCU_TYPE, "Document Type", new { @class = "labelRequired" })
                @Html.TextBox("DOCU_TYPE", "AL", new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AUTH, "Authority", new { @class = "labelRequired" })
                @Html.TextBox("AUTH", (string)ViewBag.AUTH, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FY, "Fiscal Year", new { @class = "labelRequired" })
                @Html.TextBox("FY", (string)ViewBag.FY, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DEPT, "Department", new { @class = "labelRequired" })
                @Html.TextBox("DEPT", (string)ViewBag.DEPT, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOCU_ID, "ID")
                @*@Html.TextBox("DOCU_ID", (string)ViewBag.DOCU_ID, new { @class = "form-control"})*@
                <input type="text" id="DOCU_ID" name="DOCU_ID" value="@ViewBag.DOCU_ID" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ENT_DT, "Entry Date")
                @Html.TextBox("ENT_DT", @DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOCU_DT, "Document Date")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DOCU_DT, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BUD_YR, "Budget Year")
                @Html.TextBox("BUD_YR", (string)ViewBag.FY, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ORG, "Organization", new { @class = "labelRequired" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ORG, new SelectList(Model.Divisions, "ORGNUM", "ORGNUM"), "Select one", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FUND, "Fund", new { @class = "labelRequired" })
                @Html.TextBox("FUND", (string)ViewBag.FUND, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ACCT, "Acct", new { @class = "labelRequired" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ACCT, new { @class = "form-control capitalize" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ACCT, "",  new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DEPT_OBJ, "Dept. Obj")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DEPT_OBJ, new { @class = "form-control" })
                <br /><span>(DEPT. OBJ = OBJ + SUB OBJ - EX. 33450)</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DESP, "Description")
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.DESP, new { @class = "form-control capitalize", @rows = "4"})                    
                </div>                
            </div>


            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AMOUNT, "Amount")
                <div class="input-group input-group col-lg-10 col-sm-11">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AMOUNT, new { @class = "form-control auto" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RECV_DT, "Document Date Recd")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RECV_DT, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OUT_DT, "Date to Atcg/Div")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OUT_DT, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="documentSave"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i> Save</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="documentClear"> Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#DOCU_DT').datepicker();
            $('#RECV_DT').datepicker();
            $('#OUT_DT').datepicker();
            $('.auto').autoNumeric('init');
            if ($('#ORG').val() != "" && ($('#ACCT').val()).length >= 6)
                $('#documentSave').removeAttr("disabled");
            else
                $('#documentSave').attr("disabled", true);

        });
        $('#ORG').change(function () {
            if ($('#ORG').val() != "" && ($('#ACCT').val()).length >= 6)
                $('#documentSave').removeAttr("disabled");
            else
                $('#documentSave').attr("disabled", true);
        });
        $('#ACCT').change(function () {
            if ($('#ORG').val() != "" && ($('#ACCT').val()).length >= 6)
                $('#documentSave').removeAttr("disabled");
            else
                $('#documentSave').attr("disabled", true);

        });

        $('#documentClear').click(function () {
            $('#DOCU_DT').val("");
            $('#BUD_YR').val("");
            $('#ORG').val("");
            $('#ACCT').val("");
            $('#DEPT_OBJ').val("");
            $('#DESP').val("");
            $('#AMOUNT').val("");
            $('#RECV_DT').val("");
            $('#OUT_DT').val("");
            return false;
        });
        $('#documentSave').click(function () {

            if ($('#ORG').val() != "") {
                $('form').submit();
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Every time the code run, it inserts the same record twice. If comment out the line ModelState.AddModelError(), then it work fine without any issue (which mean it inserts one record).

Comment: What is `ACCT`? How can it be < 5 (numeric) and support `substring` (string) at the same time?

Comment: It should be model.ACCT.Length < 5. I tried to rearrange the code by putting in the check of ModelState.IsValid, but it does not work.

Comment: I have noticed that when I tested the application using IE11, the duplicate records happened. But when I tested it using Firefox, the duplicate did not occur. What could be the culprit to cause the duplicate records to be inserted into the table if it only happens to a specific browser.

Comment: The problem is obviously elsewhere, show the entire, unedited controller action and the view.

Comment: The codes are the controller action and the view. Can you point out what are the issues that cause the duplicate records to be inserted and it only happens on IE 11 browser, but not in Firefox or Chrome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely this:

```
    $('#documentSave').click(function () {

        if ($('#ORG').val() != "") {
            $('form').submit();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    });
```

`#documentSave` is a button inside the form; according to [HTML 5 W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) for `type`, "The missing value default is the Submit Button state".  So, your button is acting like a submit button, and you are also calling `$('form').submit()` inside your click event -- hence the double submit.

Firefox might be killing the javascript based submit when it attempts to post and redirect to the form action, that's the only explanation I can come up with why it is happening only in IE.  But the fact it behaves differently in different browsers screams "client side javascript problem".

Try adding `type="button"` to your button.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It is the answered. Adding the type='button' to the Save button solved the issue.